# How to see what class was passed into template in Rider as an argument?

Tags: c#, debugging, generics, ide, rider

I am debugging C# templates in Rider a lot and would like to know whether or not it is possible and if yes, then how to see what class is coming into template in Rider?

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }

        public void DoSomething<T>() {
            //What is a type of T?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "template"? A T4 template? Or are your talking about generics?

Comment: @nvoigt, I am talking about generics. I am talking about classes which are passed as parameters into functions.

Comment: When exactly do you want to see it? It's hard to believe the IDE cannot show you the type of a variable while debugging...

Comment: @nvoigt, I want to see it when I am in the function into which was passed the class as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a fresh install and the default settings, you can see the variable type in the "Variables" window that you can see when you debug:

[image]

Comment: But what if I pass just a class without any parameters?

Comment: What do you mean a class without parameters? What type do you want to know if there are no parameters? Please post an example so I don't have to guess what you want.

Comment: I mean a function which takes as a parameter(s) only classes, but not variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think the previously marked answer is correct, but only for a specific case scenario.

If I understand the question correctly, it can be rephrased to "How to inspect the type of a generic parameter using Rider debugger?" If so @nvoigt's answer is correct in the sense that the debugger shows you the type of each variable in the scope of the breakpoint. Thus in the shown example:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T arg)
{
    ...
}
```

The type of `argument` is easily readable in the Variables window:
[image]

However if the `generic argument 'T'` is not the type of the `method argument 'arg'` as in:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(string arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Then `arg` will be of type `string` as was defined. In that case you need to look at the Frames window - to the left ot Variables. There, on the first line you will be able to see the method where the execution is halted (by the breakpoint) and if you expand that window you will see something like:

```
Program.DoSomething<TypePassedAsGenericArgument>()
```

where `TypePassedAsGenericArgument` will be the full name of the type, a.k.a - namespace + class name:

[image]

I think this clarification might help some new coders out there. Go get those BUGS!